# Strange output in mq_receive with queues in linux

Tags: c, linux, struct, queue, send

I am working with queues with 2 diferent files on linux based system.

I am sending a struct by `mq_send()` and receiving with `mq_receive()` in another file.

When I used a `char *` that worked perfectly, but now, I put my struct, I convert it with `(char *)` and the sent happen, but I dont receive what I have to, and the number of bytes received in receive is always `bytes received: 18446744073709551615`

my struct is like:

```
struct men
{
    int a;
    int b;
    };
```

I also put the sizeof of the struct in `mq_send()` and `mq_receive()` and also in the attributes of the queue in `.mq_msgsize`.

I tried hard to find what is the problem, changing the sizes and whatever and I couldnt find the error.

Thank you!

Comment: What about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044963/send-struct-in-mq-send?

Comment: Swearing is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

18446744073709551615 is -1 mapped to an unsigned 64-bit integer.  That indicates that mq_receive() failed.  You'll need to look at `errno` to determine how it failed.

You shouldn't need to change the .mq_msgsize.  I'd stick with mq_open(), as this is a pretty small structure.