# Using POSIX API mq_send() and mq_receive() between threads to exchange huge amount of data on embedded realtime

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, pthreads, posix

I'm new to POSIX and experimenting with message queues on an embedded real time system.
I have one thread which produces the data and other thread which consumes the data.

My question is how I can use mq_send() and mq_receive() most effectively  when dealing with huge amount of data?

The POSIX message size is limited to MQ_MSGSIZE 500 .
So I woould just think of passing the pointer to the address where the produced data is stored in the shared RAM.
The mq_receive() would just read the address where the data is stored and cast it to the appropriate type in order to operate on the data.

Let's say I have something like (just as illustration, presented as pseudocode and not compiled):

```
typedef struct
    {
        uint8 a;
        uint16 b:
        uint32 c;
        float32 d;
        /*....*/
        float x;
       
    } theStructElements
    
    
    typedef struct
    {  
        theStructElements    elements[10000]
    } theStruct_t
    
    theStruct_t instanceOfmyStruct;
    
    /*Let's say the size o sizeof(theStruct_t) is 1000000 bytes (1.0MB)*/
    
    mq_maxmsg = 10;
    q_msgsize = sizeof(theStruct_t *);
    msg_hdl = mq_open(...)
    
    /*PRODUCER THREAD*/
    void *threadA(void *arg)
    {
    
        while(1)
        {
            /*some funtion here which fills theStruct_t with values*/
            instanceOfmyStruct.elements.a = 2;
            instanceOfmyStruct.elements.b = 4;
            instanceOfmyStruct.elements.c = 6;
            /*....*/
            instanceOfmyStruct.elements.f = 8.2;
            
            
            /*store the pointer value in a variable, and pass that pointer*/
            theStruct_t *myDataToSendPtr = &instanceOfmyStruct
            
            mq_send(mqd, ( const char *)myDataToSendPtr, sizeof(theStruct_t *),0);
            
            
        }
    }
    
    /*CONSUMER THREAD*/
    void *threadB(void *arg)
    {
        char message[sizeof(theStruct_t)];
        while(1)
        {
            /*Get the Pointer to the Data in RAM*/
            mq_receive(mqd,(char *)message, sizeof(theStruct_t *), NULL);
            theStruct_t *receivedMessage = (theStruct_t *)Message;
            
            consumeData(receivedMessage)
        }
    }
```

What is your opinion on it?

Comment: "ideologically correct" makes this sound like a request for an opinion.  We can be opinionated, but we expect questions to afford ostensibly authoritative answers.

Comment: *So I woould just think of passing the pointer to the address where the produced data is stored in the shared RAM.* And how would you ensure the pointer is valid in two different processes?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is an Inter-Thread Communication. So I would expect if mq_send() sends the Pointer to the address than mq_receive() would contain the pointer to the address of the shared resource.

Comment: Message queues are normally an IPC (inter-process communication) method.  _The [`mq_open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html)
function shall establish the connection between a process and a message queue with a message queue descriptor._  Are you sure it's appropriate to be using a message queue as an ITC method?  It can probably work, and you can probably pass addresses as part of the data in the message and the address should be valid in the receiving thread as well as the sending thread.  This would be more dangerous between processes, of course.

Comment: [Thread-safe queue that supports multiple producers and consumers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924) And yes, you can simply put a pointer in it. (In fact, that's exactly what it expects as-written.)

Comment: @ikegami   MQ_MSGSIZE   500  as per definition in tx_posix.h. As long as I send not more than 500 bytes everything runs well. I read the bytes by the return value of mq_receive(). If it is more than 500 bytes the system crashes. But in the reference implementation I'm only pasing the pointer, not the data itself. How can this be?

Comment: To be clear, when I said "you can simply put a pointer in it", I was referring to the solution I linked just before.

Comment: @JohnDoe, "*But in the reference implementation I'm only pasing the pointer, not the data itself*" -- in the code presented, you are passing only a pointer to the data *to `mq_send()`*, but that just tells `mq_send()` where to find the data to include in the message. That pointer is not itself the message contents.  If you want the message ***contents*** to be a pointer, then you need to store the pointer value in a variable, and pass a pointer to that variable (and the size of that variable's type).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was basically doing the same as here mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044963/send-struct-in-mq-send  But why is this marked as accepted answer?

Comment: @JohnDoe, the accepted answer there demonstrates sending the struct *contents*, not a pointer to the struct, as the body of the message.  That's not viable for you because your struct is too large.  You seemed to think that you were instead sending a message containing the value of the pointer, but that is not the case, as my previous comment explains in a bit more detail.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have adapted the code in the question. I'm not very sure if I understood it so therefore could you have a look again and give your opinion on it?

Comment: @JohnDoe, the new version is not usefully different from the old.  I guess you're having trouble distinguishing between pointers and the (distinct) data to which they point, which is not uncommon for inexperienced C programmers.  But I have already told you what you need to do (on the sending side), so I'm not sure what else to say there.  At least I'll add that what you do on the receiving side should be the reverse.

Comment: Or perhaps you would be better off not using POSIX message queues at all.  Yours seems fundamentally to be a producer / consumer problem, and you should be able to find a lot of advice and examples of those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Allright, thanks for your help. I thought I could use the POSIX send and receive functionality to exchange data between threads together with mutexes. But in this case seems to use only mutex or semaphores to synchronize access to shared data would be enough.

Comment: @JohnDoe: only semaphores, maybe.  If you want to use mutexes, though, then you will probably need to combine that with one or more condition variables.  Again, you can find information about that by studying up on producer / consumer problems.