# IPC Queue in C - Dynamic sized messages

Tags: c, ipc

The intent is to concatenate certain file pattern in a folder. Let us say a folder named

```
abc
```

has files with sub string

```
score
```

like score_01.csv score_02.csv score_03.csv and likewise 100s of files

The basic concept of the below program is to accept two commandline parameters, one is folder and other is file pattern.

```
gcc program.c -o program
./program my_folder score
```

The program goes inside the my_folder and starts traversing the files, reads them and then pushes them into the IPC queue. And there is a consumer started in the beginning of the program using pthread. This consumer has to read and print.

It seem am not correctly doing msgsnd or msgrcv

Additionally, if I try to print the data buffer before msgsnd, it prints differently in Mac OS - no issues, whereas in Ubuntu, it prints few lines and then scattered text comes up

```
// File name program.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


key_t key;
int msgid;

typedef struct {
    long msg_type;
    char* buffer;
    size_t length;
} bufferPack;


char* fileBuffer(char* filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    return string;
} 

void walk_dir(const char *path, char* wildcard)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        char *name = entry->d_name;
        char full_name[1024];

        if (strstr(name, wildcard ) == NULL )
            continue;

        snprintf(full_name, sizeof(full_name), "%s/%s", path, name);
        bufferPack pack;
        pack.msg_type = 1;
        pack.buffer = fileBuffer(full_name);
        pack.length = strlen(pack.buffer);
        msgsnd(msgid, &pack, sizeof(bufferPack), 0);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

void* consumer(void* arg) {
    bufferPack pack; 
    while (1) {
        int rec = msgrcv(msgid, &pack, sizeof(bufferPack), 1, 0);    
        if (rec == -1) 
            // No message in queue
            continue;
        printf("%s\n", pack.buffer);
        free(pack.buffer);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if ((key = ftok("/tmp", 'A')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t thread;                             
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, consumer, NULL);

    walk_dir(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen(pack.buffer)` requires the buffer to be a null-terminated string. But `fileBuffer()` never adds a null terminator (although it allocated space for it with `fsize+1`).

```
char* fileBuffer(char* filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
    string[fsize] = '\0'; // add null terminator
    fclose(f);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, `strlen(pack.buffer)` *may* "work" if the (binary) file contains a zero byte.

Comment: That's not working in any reasonable sense of the word, except that it doesn't read past the end of the buffer. But this is reading CSV files, not binary files.

Comment: My bad, on that null terminator. But surprisingly it worked in Mac OS whereas not in Linux / Ubuntu. But still I am not able to get it to print from the consumer printf.

Comment: You were just lucky, there happened to be a 0 in the byte after the allocated block.

Comment: BTW, you have a memory leak. You never `free(pack.buffer)`

Comment: I am dong it in consumer as that is the place where I have to finally use it

Comment: I didn't notice that you were sending the pointer through the queue, not the string. Note that this will only work when the producer and consumer are in the same process. Message queues are usually used for inter-process communication.

Comment: I can send the string but the problem in that case is I wouldn't know size, as each file data size might be different. Using pack buffer data is a pointer, so I can use it and all I have to do is fetch sizseof(bufferPack)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013628/sending-variable-size-buffer-over-message-queue